# Meaning of "the kynge gaf hem leue for fayne wold he haue ben accorded with her"

Tags: meaning, literature, archaicisms, middle-english

Here is a fragment of [*Le Morte d'Arthur*](https://archive.org/stream/lemortedarthuror00malouoft#page/36/mode/2up/search/gaf+hem+leue+for+fayne) by Sir Thomas Malory:

> Thenne alle the barons by one assent prayd the Kynge of accord betwixe the lady Igrayne and hym / the kynge **gaf hem leue / for fayne** wold he haue ben accorded with her

1. Does accord between the king and lady mean marriage?
2. What's the meaning of the phrase in bold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- the modern meaning is 'agreement'. metaphorically it could mean marriage but... checking the OED we get a similar quote as an example under the primary (and earliest) meaning:

> a. With reference to people: agreement, harmony, reconciliation; an instance of this.
>
> 1485   Malory's Morte Darthur (Caxton) i. ii. sig. a.ij,   Alle the barons by one assent prayd the kynge of accord betwixe the lady Igrayne and hym.

- I can only attempt a guess at a more modern reading:

> ...the king gave him leave, for fain would he have been accorded with her.

Comment: I belive the "hem" here is not *him,* but rather *them* ("alle the barons"). "[Hem](https://sites.fas.harvard.edu/~chaucer/teachslf/less-5.htm)" is the older English third-person plural pronoun thought to be the ancestor of modern English *'em.*

Comment: @sumelic Thank you for the link to this great source, can't come off it.